# Uniqueness of Rank of Free Module

Tags: modules, free-modules

Dummit and Foote gives the following definition for a free module:

"An $R$-module $F$ is said to be *free* on the subset $A$ of $F$ if for every nonzero element $x$ of $F$, there exist unique nonzero elements $r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_n$ or $R$ and unique $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ in $A$ such that $x = r_1a_1 + r_2a_2 + \cdots + r_na_n$, for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. In this situation we say $A$ is a *basis* or *set of free generators* for $F$. If $R$ is a commutative ring the cardinality of $A$ is called the *rank* of $F$."

This definition seems to imply that the rank of a free module on a commutative ring is unique, but I can't figure out why this must be the case.

Comment: That is simply because the quotient rings by maximal ideals are fields, and the dimension of a vector space over a field is well-defined.

Comment: @Bernard would you mind elaborating on this? Where should I look to find a maximal ideal in this setup?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: demonstrate that dimension is unique for vector spaces.

Step 2: consider a ring $R$, and take some maximal ideal $M$. Let $k = R / M$ be the residue field. (Note that this proof doesn’t work for the zero ring - why?).

Suppose we have some isomorphism $R^{\oplus S} \cong R^{\oplus J}$. Consider the extension of scalar functor $F : R-mod \to k-vec$, which is the left adjoint of the restriction of scalars functor $k-vec \to R-mod$. The functor $F$ can be explicitly described as $M \mapsto M \otimes_R k$. Now $F$ takes $R^{\oplus W}$ to $k^{\oplus W}$ for any set $W$, so the functor gives us an isomorphism $k^{\oplus S} \cong k^{\oplus J}$. Thus, we have $|S| = |J|$, since the dimension of a vector space is unique. $\square$

Note that the above proof requires choice. I do not know if a proof without choice is possible, and I do not know whether we can prove this theorem (or some special cases) constructively. It is an interesting exercise.

Edit: for finite ranks, this is provable without choice. We can express “$R^n$ is not isomorphic to $R^m$” as a statement $phi(n, m)$ in the first-order theory of rings. We would like to show that for all $n, m$, we can prove $\phi(n, m)$ from the ring axioms. This can be phrased as a statement $\Phi$ in first-order arithmetic.

Now assuming choice, we know that each $\phi(n, m)$ is true. Thus, completeness shows each $\phi(n, m)$ is provable. So $\Phi$, a statement in first-order arithmetic, follows.

But any first-order arithmetic statement that can be proved with choice can be proved without it by relativising to $L$. So $\Phi$ can be proved without choice.

Then each $\phi(n, m)$ is indeed provable in the theory of rings, and therefore true.

The hard part, of course, is trying to do things for infinite bases or completely constructively.

Comment: here's an easier proof without choice: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2651806/348926

Comment: @LukasHeger That is indeed easier for the finite dimensional case, and it’s constructive. But unfortunately we still have an issue with infinite-rank free modules.

Comment: The fact that the dimension of an infinite-dimensional vector space is unique requires (I think) the ultrafilter lemma, so there is no hope for a constructive proof in that case.

Comment: Incidentally, here's a proof that requires only the ultrafilter lemma and so technically is without choice: choose a prime ideal $P$ and then tensor with the fraction field of $R/P$, then argue as in your answer. The existence of a prime ideal is weaker than that of a maximal ideal and equivalent to the ultrafilter lemma.